# How to use binary files. Overwriting specific bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, binaryfiles

I'm writing a program in python, and would like to be able to write to specific bytes in a binary file. I tried to do this in the shell with a small binary file containing the numbers 0 through 15, but I can't figure out how to do so. Below is the code I just entered into the shell with comments to demonstrate what I am trying to do:

```
>>> File=open("TEST","wb") # Opens the file for writing.
>>> File.write(bytes(range(16))) # Writes the numbers 0 through 15 to the file.
16
>>> File.close() # Closes the file.
>>> File=open("TEST","rb") # Opens the file for reading, so that we can test that its contents are correct.
>>> tuple(File.read()) # Expected output: (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
>>> File.close() # Closes the file.
>>> File=open("TEST","wb") # Opens the file for writing.
>>> File.seek(3) # Moves the pointer to position 3. (Fourth byte.)
3
>>> File.write(b"\x01") # Writes 1 to the file in its current position.
1
>>> File.close() # Closes the file.
>>> File=open("TEST","rb") # Opens the file for reading, so that we can test that its contents are correct.
>>> tuple(File.read()) # Expected output: (0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
(0, 0, 0, 1)
>>> File.close()
>>> File=open("TEST","wb") # I will try again using apend mode to overwrite.
>>> File.write(bytes(range(16)))
16
>>> File.close()
>>> File=open("TEST","ab") # Append mode.
>>> File.seek(3)
3
>>> File.write(b"\x01")
1
>>> File.close()
>>> File=open("TEST","rb")
>>> tuple(File.read()) # Expected output: (0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1)
>>> File.close()
```

My desired output is as shown, but `"wb"` seems to erase all the data in the file, while `"ab"` can't seek backwards.

How would I achieve my desired output without rewriting the whole file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you open a file for writing with `w`, the file is *truncated*, all contents removed. You need to open the file for reading and writing with `r+` instead. From the `open()` function documentation:

> `'w'`     open for writing, **truncating the file first**

and

> For binary read-write access, the mode 'w+b' opens and truncates the file to 0 bytes. 'r+b' opens the file without truncation.

Because the file was truncated first, seeking to position 3 then writing `\x01` has the first few bytes filled in with `\x00` for you.

Opening a file in append mode usually restricts access to the new portion of the file only, so anything past the first 16 bytes. Again, from the documentation:

> Other common values are [...] and `'a'` for appending (**which on some Unix systems, means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position**).

(*bold emphasis in quoted sections mine*). This is why your `\x01` byte ends up right at the end in spite of the `File.seek(3)` call.

`r` does not truncate a file and gives you full range of the contents with `seek()`; `r+` adds write access to that mode. Demo with `'r+b'`:

```
>>> with open('demo.bin', 'wb') as f:
...     f.write(bytes(range(16)))
...
16
>>> with open('demo.bin', 'rb') as f:
...     print(*f.read())
...
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
>>> with open('demo.bin', 'r+b') as f:  # read and write mode
...     f.seek(3)
...     f.write(b'\x01')
...
3
1
>>> with open('demo.bin', 'rb') as f:
...     print(*f.read())
...
0 1 2 1 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember properly, you have to open the file in "Append mode" or it will simply erase everything and start from scratch, and then when you use `seek(3)` you just create those 3 0's and then you write the 1. I'll investigate further on how to write directly to a position but you may have to read the whole file, modify, write the whole file again.

You can actually read about this behaviour in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased)

Comment: I have shown in my question that append mode doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: Or rather, that append mode does work - it enforces that writes go to the end. It is specifically not meant for modifying existing contents.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I wrote a bit too fast since I had to go toa meeting but wasn't intending that append mode was your solution here :) Martijin did a much better work at explaining how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is another mode: `"r+b"`. (as shown by other answers.)

Here is the solution in the shell from where the file left off:

```
>>> File=open("TEST","r+b") # Opens file for reading and writing.
>>> File.seek(3)
3
>>> File.write(b"\x01")
1
>>> File.close()
>>> File=open("TEST","rb")
>>> tuple(File.read()) # Expected output: (0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1)
(0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1)
>>> File.close()
```